# Set CodeIgniter error messages using Form Validation config file

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Is CodeIgniter able to interpret `config/form_validation.php` to display appropriate error messages?

There is a way with validation when using controller: `$this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', '{field} must have at least {param} characters.');`

Current validation rules (and the last array is what I'm interested in, if there is a way to add validation messages in the same array as the rules.):

```
'users' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'first_name',
            'label' => 'First Name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'last_name',
            'label' => 'Last Name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'email_address',
            'label' => 'Email Address',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email'
        ,   'messages'=> array('valid_email'=>'Please make sure your email is correct.')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Read And Follow The Given Example in Below Link.I Think This Will Help You.

[Custom Error Messages - Form Validation Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-rules-using-an-array)

CodeIgniter allows to add validation messages as described in the docs. The array would be as follows:

```
'users' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'first_name',
            'label' => 'First Name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'last_name',
            'label' => 'Last Name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'email_address',
            'label' => 'Email Address',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email'
        ,   'errors'=> array('valid_email'=>'Please make sure your email is correct.')))
```